# Jscript inside Batch File

Tags: batch-file, jscript

I want run this below code in `bat` file:

```bat
@echo off
echo ---------------------------------
ping -n 1 google.com | find "TTL=" >nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    echo google = OFFLINE
) else (
    echo google = ONLINE
)
```

Then I want this next code below will run also in `if errorlevel 1`:

```js
WshShell.AppActivate "Mozilla Firefox"
WshShell.SendKeys "google Offline"
WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

How do I run the code above?
The last code normally run in `vbs` extension, but I want run it in `bat` extension.

Comment: Your first line should have an opening jscript comment block so that it skips over the batch file code. And your ending comment should have an asterisk as well.

Comment: First line before the batch file code to open the jscript comment block: `@if (@X)==(@Y) @end  /* harmless hybrid line that begins a JScript comment`. Line to close the jscript comment block.  `************ JScript portion ***********/`  Jscript code goes after this.

Comment: Please avoid Frankenscript like that, particularly if you don't have experience in either language in the first place. Create two files, and call one from the other.

Comment: Your cscript line says you want to use JSCRIPT.  If you want a hybrid Vbscript and batch file code then that completely changes the way you do it.

Comment: Update your question with your updated code and comments and then remove your comment.

Comment: i already update my script.. please help me @Squashman

Comment: Please learn how to [format code properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)!

Answer (score 3):

This is a "Frankenscript"; I like such a term!  ;)

```
@set @a=0; /*
@echo off
ECHO --------------------------------- 
ping -n 1 google.com | find "TTL=" >nul 
if errorlevel 1 (
   echo google = OFFLINE
   cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
   if NextSection == JScript (      */
      WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
      WshShell.AppActivate("Mozilla Firefox");
      WshShell.SendKeys("google Offline");
      WshShell.SendKeys("{ENTER}"); /*
   )
) else ( 
   echo google = ONLINE
)
rem */
```